# jsf ajax process different parts of form

Tags: ajax, jsf, partial

I have detected a strange behaviour of ajax:

I have one form with some ajax-components (e.g. buttons or just textfields with ajax-submit on focuslost).

When I process e.g. the first textbox, everything is fine in the backing bean (viewscoped). But when I process the second textbox some seconds later, the values from the first submit are lost completely, and only the second value is in the backing bean.

is this normal?

Comment: That doesn't sound normal, no. A @ViewScoped bean will live as long as you're submitting the form to the same view again and again. The bean will be lost on navigation or if an exception occurs.

Comment: You might want to check the submit to see if you're actually overwriting the first textbox value with an empty string or null on the second submit. Put some log statements in your setters, or something like that.

Comment: Do you have the right combination of annotations on the bean?

Comment: Yeah, better post some code, Niko. A snippet from your facelets page and backing bean.